# PowerShell error "Error: Reference isn't valid." when executing multi column Excel sort

Tags: powershell

Why does this PowerShell script give the error "Error: Reference isn't valid." when ececuting the line "$Range.Sort($Range.Columns.Item("A"), 1, $Range.Columns.Item("G"), 1, $Range.Columns.Item("D"), 1)?

```
# Load the Excel COM object
$FilePath = "C:\PSSI_Trunks\PSSI_TRUNKS_Input.xlsx"
if (Test-Path $FilePath){Write-Output "found $FilePath"}
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

# Open the Excel file
$Inputworkbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$InputSheet = $Inputworkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

# Define the range to be sorted
$RowCount = $InputSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
$SortArea = "A2:I" + $RowCount

$Range = $InputSheet.Range($SortArea)

# Sort the range by columns A, G, and D
$Range.Sort($Range.Columns.Item("A"), 1, $Range.Columns.Item("G"), 1, $Range.Columns.Item("D"), 1)
```

Excel file should have sorted rows 2 through number of rows by columns A, G, and D.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) suggest that the 4th parameter is specific to pivot tables, so _maybe_ skipping it helps: `$Range.Sort($Range.Columns.Item("A"), 1, $Range.Columns.Item("G"),, 1, $Range.Columns.Item("D"), 1)`